# I can't find the xPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath, instagram

Please help... I can't seem to find the xPath.

This is the source: view-source:http://www.pikore.com/fun_bestvids

I need to scrape the @Content in this part of the source:

```
<meta name="description" content="See Funny Videos (@fun_bestvids) Instagram profile on Pikore. Daily The Best &amp; Funniest Videos
Tag #funbestvids to your videos!
postbestvids@gmail.com
Email me for credit
・・・">
```

Thank you.

Comment: Okay, what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried to use: //content[x] and then replacing the X with the index that the content was at. but for some reason that didn't work. I don't how how to find the path because there are more than one label. @alecxe

Answer (score 3):

You can locate the element based on the element's `name` attribute, then get the `content` value:

```
//meta[@name="description"]/@content
```